# Let $A=\{a_1,...,a_n\}$ and $F$ be all functions $f:A\rightarrow \{0,1\}$. Is $g:F \rightarrow P(A)$, $g(f)=\{a\in A:f(a)=1\}$ bijective?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> For $n\in\mathbb N$ let $A=\{a_1,...,a_n\}$ and $F$ be all functions $f:A\rightarrow \{0,1\}$.
>
> Now let $g:F \rightarrow P(A)$, $g(f)=\{a\in A:f(a)=1\}$.
>
> Is $g$ surjective or injective?

Maybe I'm interpreting it wrong, but I see $g$'s domain being $\{0,1\}$ because it's all functions that map $A$ to a $0$ or $1$ then if $a$ is in $A$ it returns a $1$? But I'm not sure how that gets mapped to the powerset of $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain of $g$ is not $\{0,1\}$, rather this is the codomain of a map $f\in F$. The domain of $g$ has $2^n$ elements since there are $n$ elements of $A$ and $2$ choices for each $a_i$ to be sent under a map in $F$. Notice that this is also the cardinality of $P(A)$. Therefore, $g$ is a bijection if and only if it is surjective.

Given a subset $A'\subseteq A$, could you construct $f\in F$ such that $g(f)=A'$ (thus showing surjectivity of $g$)? If you want a spoiler:

> Try $$f(a):=\begin{cases}1 \qquad a\in A' \\ 0 \qquad a\notin A'\end{cases}$$

Comment: How would I show it's injective?

Comment: By my comment it is enough to show surjectivity. Indeed, since the domain and codomain of $g$ are of equal (finite) cardinality, surjectivity implies injectivity. But if you want a more concrete argument of injectivity: suppose $g(f_1)=g(f_2)$, then $f_1^{-1}(\{1\})=f_2^{-1}(\{1\})$ and thus $$f_1^{-1}(\{0\})=A\setminus f_1^{-1}(\{1\})=A\setminus f_2^{-1}(\{1\})=f_2^{-1}(\{0\})$$ and thus $f_1=f_2$.